# Select a range of bits from bytes

Tags: c, bit

[edit] Please close/delete, I was just counting from the wrong side.

I'm working with this function with the hopes of extracting some number of bits from a starting position in a value.

```
// Extract K bits from position P in the value
int getBits(int value, int k, int p)
{
   return (((1 << k) - 1) & (value >> (p - 1)));
}
```

When I test it with the int 2303 (0000100011111111) I get an output of 15.

```
printf("%d\n", getBits(2303,4,4));
```

I'm trying to grab the 4 bits starting at position 4 to make it print out 8. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "starting at position 4" --> is that goal 4 from the left (MSBit) or from the right (LSBits)?

Comment: Yep, I didn't realise cause i'm working with network data and i need to read the data in chunks from left to right :P

Comment: Tip: also use _unsigned_ types and avoid _signed_ shifting and mask issues.

Answer (score 3):

The four bits at position 4 (what most people would call "bit 3") of your number are `1111`, so you're getting the expected output:

```
0000100011111111
         ^^^^ these ones
```

It looks like you wanted:

```
getBits(2303, 4, 9)
```

Comment: Just realised I'm counting from the wrong side ... it's been a long day

Answer (score 2):

The position parameter starts from the least significant bit.  In other words, count from the right, not the left.

Comment: I'm an idiot...

Comment: Nah, just a human... :)

Comment: The good and old confusion about big endian  and little endian representation

Comment: @braindf - endianness has nothing to do with bit order. It refers to the ordering of bytes in a word.